# Magento Checkbox for bundle products needs qty

Tags: php, mysql, magento

With a bundled product in magento you can select various types of options - drop down for example adds a Qty box so you may choose the quantity of items from the drop down.

I am using Checkboxes instead as i need many choices and need a Qty box associated - how is this possible? I've spent hours trying to code this.

Comment: How far did you get, and what is the part gives you trouble?

Comment: Any solution about that please?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a radio button you can allow user defined qty